# Can Intel's icc compiler produce AST, CFG, and/or IR?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, icc, intermediate-language, control-flow-graph

When using clang, I've found it useful to examine the abstract syntax tree (AST), control-flow graph (CFG), and LLVM IR that it produces.

I've started looking at Intel's icc compiler (version 15.0.2), and I can't find any documentation that tells me if/how I can get it to produce those same artifacts.

The closest thing I've found is that it can produce fat link-time objects, which contain IR among other things.  However, I don't see anything suggesting that the IR is meant to be comprehensible by users.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get these artifacts from icc?